# Is Azure Service Fabric Stateful Service State shared across partitions?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm working on a Stateful Service that manages inventory for a bunch of products for our customers. Each customer belongs to a tenant group which may have an instance of this stateful service in his own partition. So a tenant with Id 10 and a tenant with Id 11 may be in a same partition (let's assume).

Each tenant has access to Inventory for an Item with Id = 100 (for example). Each time a person wants to purchase this item, I check if the Inventory exists for this tenant, if not, I notify the calling application (a Reliable Actor in this case) and let him know.

However, I've noticed that I was storing a reliable dictionary with the Key of the Item Id and the inventory counts. I noticed that even though the services belong to separate partitions, they still accessed the same object. Is this true that even though these services reside under different partitions, that they still have the same underlying state?

If so, would it make more sense to store this information directly at the Actor level? I didn't see reliable collections at the actor level and thus I built a Stateful Service that would be invoked by an Actor but in my prior Akka implementations, I would store this state at the Actor level.

I'm curious if anyone has implemented something similar and could shed light on this.

Thank You in advance for your responses!

Anup Marwadi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, state is not shared between different partitions. That would defeat the purpose; keeping a large dataset manageable by dividing it.

Consider implementing multi-tenancy by creating an Application instance per tenant. This way there will never be any sharing of data between tenants, and you can backup/on-/off-board tenants easily.

[This](http://henidak.com/2015/07/service-fabric-partitions/) article explains service partitions very well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought that too but something didn't seem right when I started testing. I will need to review my code to confirm. I will keep you posted.

Comment: Hello, so I finally realized what the issue was. In my local deployment, the Partition count was set to 1 and even though the Partition Key was different for the 2nd request, it would end up going to the same partition. After increasing the partition count to 10, things started looking much better. Thank you.